# Developing with Flask and Mustache

Tags: flask, mustache

I'm using Flask to make a web app and using mustache templates (alongwith sammy.js). I'm running the app with `debug=True` but whenever I make changes in the mustache template (or other static assets) I need to clear the browser cookies and cache to make sure that the changes are visible. Other times, I need to use Chrome in `incognito` mode to see the changes. How can I avoid this hassle? Is there a way to see the changes by just reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to deactivate the cache in your browser. In Chrome is there a great checkbox under the settings of the web inspector.

A other way should be to remove the cache http header keys. There is a flask settings key `SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT` with that you should control the cache lifetime of static files.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your static assets using the [Flask-Assets](http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/flask-assets/) extension. The library the extension uses allows for cache busting.

You might also want to render your mustache templates into the template itself, rather than an external javascript file, when developing. The [Flask-mustachejs](https://github.com/bradleywright/flask-mustachejs) flask extension enables this, and has documentation on loading the templates differently in development and production.